# How to improve accuracy when querying for google geocode api?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-geocoding-api, geocode

I am working on a event planner app where I need to validate the address entered by the user.

At the moment I am not worried about entering the wrong door/unit number or entering the unit number that doesn't exist.

I only want to deal with the cases where user enter general words like Boardroom/Meeting room/ etc as location.

The problem is geocode api doesn't provide anything to improve accuracy.

The following api:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=no+location&key=AIz*****bxyiI

has the address typed as "no location"

But this query gives the result

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "2120",
                "short_name": "2120",
                "types": [
                    "street_number"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Main Street",
                "short_name": "Main St",
                "types": [
                    "route"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Parsons",
                "short_name": "Parsons",
                "types": [
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Labette County",
                "short_name": "Labette County",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_2",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Kansas",
                "short_name": "KS",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "United States",
                "short_name": "US",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "67357",
                "short_name": "67357",
                "types": [
                    "postal_code"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address": "2120 Main St, Parsons, KS 67357, USA",
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 37.340256,
                "lng": -95.268513
            },
            "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 37.3416049802915,
                    "lng": -95.26716401970849
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 37.3389070197085,
                    "lng": -95.26986198029151
                }
            }
        },
        "place_id": "ChIJXQvh_YcauIcRg5p7FuD3Luc",
        "plus_code": {
            "compound_code": "8PRJ+4H Parsons, Kansas, United States",
            "global_code": "86968PRJ+4H"
        },
        "types": [
            "establishment",
            "point_of_interest",
            "store"
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
```

}

I tried the following ways:

1) Depend on user input in these situations. IF the entered address is not a valid address , then user can mark the event as general event and this event need not be mapped on the map view.

2) Setup a format that address field should have at least unit number and street number. So if no number is present on address, then it is not a valid location. Even in this case 1212 wow street could give the unexpected results.

Q1) Is there a general rule to follow in these situations ? Like when to warn user about the invalid location he entered ?

Q2) Is there a way to improve the geocode query ?

From Google Documentation:

> address — The street address that you want to geocode, in the format
>   used by the national postal service of the country concerned.
>   Additional address elements such as business names and unit, suite or
>   floor numbers should be avoided.

They stated about how to query a valid address but they did not mention anything about accuracy or address validation.

I could not find other way to deal such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Google geocoding service is, explicitly, not an address validation service. Geocoding is the process of converting addresses into geographic coordinates, which you can use to place markers or position the map.

- There is no guarantee that a valid postal address will yield any result.
- There is no guarantee that an invalid postal address will be corrected.
- There is no guarantee that a non-existent postal address will return exactly zero results.

If you are interested in verification of address formatting you should look into different option. E.g. something like [SmartyStreets API](https://smartystreets.com/).

I hope this helps!